# How to retrieve value from KeyStore with AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I created a salt key in the SF KeyStore; how do i retrieve the key and use it in AMPScript? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at encrypt/decrypt symmetric functions: https://ampscript.guide/encryptsymmetric/

Comment: Not looking for symmetric keys. I just want to use the salt within my ampscript for other purposes. In the examples, it's hard coded and doesn't show how to use a keystore value.

Comment: It sounds like there's a misunderstanding around what key management in SFMC's for. It's not a "key store" or dumping ground for key value pairs that you can retrieve for whatever purpose. It's there to support SFMC encryption features in AMPScript, as zuzannamj says, along with providing keys for the likes of SFTP and GPG/PGP encryption of files.

Comment: @Macca Thank you, that's unfortunate :(